# Custom TextViews or Buttons

Tags: android, listview, textview

Can you have a TextView that is created using a number of other Views.

I would like something the user can click that contains 2 textviews and an imageView but want it to be considered as a single View.  I know this can be done using a ListView and custom XML file and I would like to deal with this in a similar manner but would rather not use a listview if possible.

Comment: why not use a listview? reasons i mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's better if you can use listview but it also can be achieved without listview. But in that case you have to manually handle everything.

Here is the basic concept:

- Create custom XML file(row.xml) for your row as you would for listview
- In your main layout file place a viewgroup for example LinearLayout or RelativeLayout which will hold the row.
- In your activity/fragment inflate the row.xml you want to show.
- addView the inflated view to your viewgroup and attach onclicklistener to your inflated row view.

These are the steps for adding view so that it looks like a list of views and it will but the problem is you have to take care of binding data to these views. I would strongly encourage you to use listview nevertheless it's worth knowing best and worst solution of a problem :).

Answer (score 1):

why you are not using list view?
To answer your question,
Yes you can.
Use a viewholder/viewbinder. Google for viewholder/viewbinder.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is acceptable answer but my advice is to not afraid the ListViews. I understand that the official documentation is horrible but you can understand the basic concepts from [here](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429) and [here](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) .

If you don't want to use list views anyway , you can put your textviews and the image view in a single LinearLayout and attach an onTouchListener on the LinearLayout.